Flexible Worker Configuration for Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Deployment
I require a specific configuration for managing my Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) module within Apache.
Currently, I have multiple services deployed on a RHEL7 Apache server, e.g. Service1, Service2, Service3, and Service4.
Each service is implemented as a separate .so file: libService1.so, libService2.so, libService3.so, and libService4.so.
Among these, Service1 and Service2 offer SOAP interfaces, while Service3 and Service4 offer REST interfaces.
At present, Apache treats all services uniformly, spawning five worker processes initially.
Consequently, all four services also have five instances running concurrently, with Apache dynamically adjusting worker processes based on system load.
My requirement is treating one of the services, specifically Service4, differently.
Apache should only spawn a single instance of Service4 and refrain from terminating the process until Apache server restarts.
Meanwhile, the remaining three services should continue behaving as before, initially spawning five instances and adjusting based on load.
My question is whether it is feasible to achieve this mixed treatment within a single Apache server through configuration changes.
If not, what alternative options exist within the Apache framework?
One potential solution could running two Apache server instances, one for the first three services and another dedicated to the fourth service.
I would appreciate any suggestions on how to fulfill this functionality.
I have very limited experinece with conguration of apache DSO in RHEL7 so could not try any thing yet.
